# How to convert from an interface{} to a struct instance

Tags: json, go

I am working on a Go module implementation to abstract communication with other peers. The idea behind the module is to send/receive messages through a MQ in a standard message format that can carry virtually any type of "entities" in it. But I am finding very difficult to solve the type convertion in Go.

Here is a snippet of what I am trying to do (https://play.golang.org/p/Orb1vNdulY1).

```
type Message struct {
    Code   string
    Entity interface{}
}

type Cartoon struct {
    Name string
    Show string
}

func main() {
    cartoon := Cartoon{Name: "Doug Funnie", Show: "Doug"}
    msg := Message{Code: "12345", Entity: cartoon}

    payload, err := json.Marshal(msg)
    fmt.Println("JSON Sent:", string(payload))

    // Here json message gets sent to a MQ broker

    // Here json message gets read by a consumer

    var message Message
    err = json.Unmarshal(payload, &message)
    fmt.Println("Message Received:", message)

    var cart Cartoon
    cart = message.Entity.(Cartoon)
    fmt.Println("Cartoon Received:", cart)
}
```

At this very line I get the following error:

```
cart = message.Entity.(Cartoon)
```

> panic: interface conversion: interface {} is map[string]interface {}, not main.Cartoon

The thing is, as this is intended to be a module for "generic" entity types, I do not know the entity type (struct) before I deliver the message to the consumer application.

So I need a way to deliver an instance of the struct to the application or even allow the consumer application to convert to the type (struct) it expects to receive.

Even if there is an easier elegant way to do what I want even if I have to change my Message struct, I may consider the solution.

The only way I figured out to solve this is to turn ***Message.Entity*** to a string field that holds the raw json content, and then the consumer app unmarshal it to the desired type. Not so elegant tho.

Raw string/json solution (https://play.golang.org/p/c9bgAbI7SZh).

Any thoughts?

Comment: Either set the Entity field to a value of the concrete type before unmarshaling, or use [json.RawMessage](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage) instead of string. It exists for exactly this use case.

Comment: How is the target type determined?  Does a field in the message specify the type, or is determined by the called function?

Comment: Actually in the proper module I am working on, there is a field that says the type name (string). But only the consumer app will know / have this type. The lib does not know about it. SO, the called function will happen to know it.

Answer (score 3):

The question asks how to convert an `interface{}` to Go type. The higher-level goal in the OPs application is to convert the variant part of a JSON message to a Go type. The higher-level problem is answered here.

If the type is known at the time the JSON is unmarshalled, then set the Entity field to a pointer to a value of the appropriate type:

```
var cart Cartoon
message := &Message{Entity: &cart}
err := json.Unmarshal(payload, message)
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/OEauxWzbtFg).

If the type is not known until after invariant part of the message is decoded, then use [json.RawMessage](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#RawMessage) to capture the entity JSON.  Decode that JSON once the type is known.

```
var entity json.RawMessage
message := &Message{Entity: &entity}
err := json.Unmarshal(payload, &message)

// ... determine target entity type using message

var cart Cartoon
err = json.Unmarshal(entity, &cart)
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/sGWqCiRE5cl)

Another option is to create a registry of types:

```
var messageTypes = map[string]reflect.Type{
    "cartoon": reflect.TypeOf(&Cartoon{}).Elem(),
}
```

and decode to a type from the registry:

```
var entity json.RawMessage
message := &Message{Entity: &entity}
err = json.Unmarshal(payload, message)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}

message.Entity = nil

if t := messageTypes[message.Type]; t != nil {
    v := reflect.New(t).Interface()
    err := json.Unmarshal(entity, v)
    if err != nil {
        // handle error
    }
    message.Entity = v
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/xaPb4cVvp6y)

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution (it is not so elegant!), if you keep struct without changes.

```
tmp, ok := message.Entity.(map[string]interface{})
if ok {
    cart.Name = tmp["Name"].(string) // inside bracket depends to the json
    cart.Show = tmp["Show"].(string)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/T9i7pYlk96h

also you can use reflect.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I can solve this problem with a lib called mapstructure.

```
var cart Cartoon
mapstructure.Decode(message.Entity, &cart)
fmt.Println("cartoon:", cart)
```

I did a succesful teste here: https://play.golang.org/p/J9V-SFz1pJE

Comment: This is no different to using json.RawMessage and json.Unmarshal, except it forces a dependency on your users, and that they use non-standard tags in their types, which is not possible if the types are defined in a third party package.